# Android-REST API request :can't read custom header parameters in server

Tags: android, rest, nginx, header

I'm trying to get response from a node.js rest server (reverse proxy with nginx).

When i try the API through postman, I'm able to read the header parameters in server. But when testing it in Android device, I get the following error:

> header undefined

here is the custom header key  name

`my_basic_key`

**OKHTTP**

```
   OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,
                "{\"socialId\":\"1080955243973\",\"provider\":\"google\",\"firstName\":\"iha\",\"lastName\":\"San\",\"email\":\"susi@gmail.com\"}");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://<domain>/user/social")
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("key", "value")
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .build();
```

**NGINX settings**

under_score_in_header is ON

Comment: how are you trying to read the header in Android ? in the code provided, you are sending a request with your headers, not reading the headers

Comment: not reading, we pass headers in API request. on Response of that we getting authentication failed

Comment: Your code seems fine. Have you tried checking your headers on https://requestb.in/ ?

Comment: Stuck on same issue.